# How to properly deal with a fixed navigation bar at the top of a webpage?

Tags: html, css

Let me explain a little more.

I've been making a webpage and I have a navigation bar at the top. I decided that I'd like it to be fixed and always showing at the top of the page.

When I did this, the top of the content which used to be below the navigation bar is now slipping underneath it because the bar does not take up that space anymore.

Is there a proper way to deal with this? I can add padding to the top of the content which means it doesn't start beneath the nav bar but this seems like it's not the best solution. Alternately I could make an invisible div beneath the navigation bar so that the space is taken up...

Any thoughts? I will add screenshots as soon as I'm able.

I'm using the "position: fixed" property for the navigation bar.

Comment: You should have the main section with some margin-top... Any specific code question that you have? Currently your question looks broad.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking... I'll add jsfiddle when I'm able to.

Comment: I would use margin, too. Not padding because that way you can't use borders on the top of your page. Don't fix the content either because that could prove hard with scrollspy. You also might want to consider making the content 100% height, which means that if you fix it from the top, you will hide some pixels beneath the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it most of the times. A margin to the main section and same to the topbar, with minus.

```css
*{
  font-size:20px;
}
topbar{
  position:fixed;
  margin-top:-20px;
 
  display:block;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
}
main{
  margin-top:20px;
 
  background:yellow;
  width:100%;
  padding-right:10px;
}
```

```html
<topbar>Hey there</topbar>
<main>
  Here is<br>
  some<br>
  text<br>
  some<br>
  text<br>
  some<br>
  text<br>
  some<br>
  text<br>
  some<br>
  text<br>
  some<br>
  text<br>
</main>
```

You can ignore all the other styles - they are for aesthetic reasons :)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've seen in practice is to wrap all the content (including the header) in a wrapper div.  Keep your header's styles the same

`position:fixed; top: 0;`

and then set padding to the top of the wrapper div that equals the header's height.